# Android - There are no accepted cards available for use with this merchant

Tags: android, stripe-payments, google-pay

I have integrated google pay integration with stripe. For that I have referred below link:

https://stripe.com/docs/google-pay

I am getting an error when I click on google pay button that "There are no accepted cards available for use with this merchant"

Answer (score 0):

This error comes because you have not set up google pay ENVIRONMENT_TEST environment. For this, you have to follow certain steps and also need to contact the Google support team.

These are the steps you need to follow to integrate google pay in the application.

1. Build your app in ENVIRONMENT_TEST with your Stripe test publishable key.
2. Reach out to Google support.
3. Send the APK pointing to ENVIRONMENT_TEST to Google support when requested.
4. Google assesses the app against their integration checklist and provides feedback if needed.
5. Google provides instructions on how to agree to their Terms of Service and ensure production access is granted.
6. Send your final production APK pointing to ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION to Google for a real-world test which includes a few transactions.
7. If all tests pass, Google clears you to publish the APK.
8. Notify Google support when your APK is 100% visible to users.